# Re-size background image

Tags: css

I have a slider and it works by loading in a background image. I need to resize this image so it fits to all screens I know what line of code I need to put in just don't quite know how to go about it. I need to add

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

to the `$style` variable, how would I go about doing this.

I tried

```
$style = "background-size: 100% 100%;, background:url('". Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . $s['image'] . "') 50% 0 no-repeat;";
```

But that loaded the background size but not the background.

```
<ul class="slides">
            <?php
            $slides = $this->getSlides();
            foreach($slides as $s) {
                $style = $content = '';
                $attr = 'data-img-height="0"';
                if ( !empty($s['image']) ) {
                    $imgSize = getimagesize(Mage::getBaseDir('media') .'/'. $s['image']);
                    if ($imgSize) {
                        $style = "background:url('". Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . $s['image'] . "') 50% 0 no-repeat;";
                        $attr = 'data-img-height="'.$imgSize[1].'"';
                    }
                }
```

Comment: place the `background-size` ***after*** the `background`, otherwise it will be overriden by `background` with the default value.

Comment: Thank you so much, i knew was going to be something easy but couldnt work it out haha. Thank you again, if you want to write it as an answer i will accept it.

Comment: You could also use the "cover" attribute of the "background" css property. The browser will then resize with aspect ration. Very handy and does not need any PHP and that improves performance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the `background-size` is `initial` (which is in fact `auto`). So when using `background` all the background-related settings before including `background-size` will be overridden by the default value or by the value set in the `background` declaration. So you should place the `background-size` after the `background` declaration. Or set the `background-image`, `background-position`, `background-repeat`, ... separately in any order you want.

Comment: thats better to write it in the answer for other members ;)

Comment: @ZahidKhan yes, I've just thought it's too basic, answering requires more explanation so sometimes without any offer to add the answer from the OP, I would not add it :)